# Migration script example to populate a table column prior to adding foreign key constraint

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to using sequelize and nodejs.  In previous web frameworks, I have built my own migration scripts.  Now I want to learn to use sequelize migration scripts.  I am looking for sample code or pseudo code on how to achieve the following.  I will write what I would normally do in PHP and MySQL:

```
if(!columnExists('tblUser','main_profile_id'))
{
$sql = "ALTER TABLE tblUser ADD COLUMN main_profile_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL";
db_execute($sql);

$sql = "UPDATE tblUser SET main_profile_id = (SELECT profile_id FROM tblProfile WHERE tblProfile.user_id = tblUser.user_id AND tblProfile.priority = 0)";
db_execute($sql);

$sql = "ALTER TABLE tblUser ADD FOREIGN KEY (`main_profile_id`) REFERENCES `tblProfile`(`profile_id`)";
db_execute($sql);

}
```

The order in which i run each of the sql statements IS IMPORTANT, because I need to make sure `tblUser.main_profile_id` is populated before I apply a foreign key constraint, otherwise I would get an error.

What would be the nodejs + sequelize translation of this?

**EDIT: I am also using Express if that helps me in anyway**

Answer (score 0):

this is a sample to write the migration script

```
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  up: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
migration.addColumn('Locations', 'PostId',
    {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: "Posts",
        referencesKey: "id"
    });

done();
  },



 down: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.removeColumn('Locations', 'PostId');
    done();
  }
};
```